# JQuery Dropdown hover

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Am having problem with a JQuery dropdown menu. On the face of it my menu is working but it's very erratic, sometimes one of the lists stays open when left.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("li ul").hide();
        $("li").hover(function() {
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle(300);
        return false;
        });   
    });
```

I've seen other people use many different ways of doing these menus. Is hover less consistent than mousein/out? Is slideToggle not the way to go? Is my code broken?

Like I said, the menus works but seems buggy to me. Any thoughts would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

The hover function accepts two parameters, both functions.  The first is for mouseover, the second is for mouseout.  Your code appears to require two mouseovers to make the item appear, and disappear.